# Hierarchical DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Are there any free user controls that offer a WPF DataGrid with the ability to have multiple children (should be a way of representing XML)?

What I want is a sort of TreeView with the ability to show an 'item name' column and 'item data' column that is user editable.

Are there any free user controls that can provide me with that?

Comment: You mean something like [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mrochon/archive/2009/10/16/displaying-hierarchical-data-in-the-datagrid.aspx) or [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24973/TreeListView)?