# TreeTable control in WPF and c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, treeview

I want to know how can I display hierarchical data in a datagrid with tree structure. I will make myself clear with the scenario

I have the following classes..

```
public class Package
{
    public String name { get; set; }
    public Measure measure { get; set; }
    public List<Class> classList { get; set; }
}

public class Class
{
    public String name { get; set; }
    public Measure measure { get; set; }
    public List<Method> methodsList { get; set; }
}

public class Method
{
    public String name { get; set; }
    public Measure measure { get; set; }
}

public class Measure
{
    public String tolc { get; set; }
    public String lloc { get; set; }
    public String ploc { get; set; }
    public String lComments { get; set; }
    public String blankLines { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to display them in a datagrid with a tree structure like this..

```
Item Name    TLOC    LLOC   PLOC   LCOMMENTS    BLANKLINES
package1     100     80     70     45           30
-class1      30      20     19     2            12
--method1    30      20     19     2            12
-class2      70      60     51     43           18
--method1    50      20     11     23           8
--method2    20      40     40     20           10
package2     50      20     10     5            5
-class       50      20     10     5            5
```

Hope I made it clear. How can I get this done using WPF in C#.
It will be very helpful, this is driving me crazy for days now.

Comment: Well you can look at this already asked [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121565/hierarchical-datagrid)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CollectionViewSource in XAML, like this:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="Packages" Source="{Binding AllCode}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <!-- Requires 'xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"' declaration. -->
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="PackageName"/>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="ClassName"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
```

Then you need enchants datagrid with group style:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1"
                  Background="{x:Null}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Packages}}"
        <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn DisplayMemberPath="PackageName"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn DisplayMemberPath="ClassName"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">                            
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="White">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <DockPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0"/>
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding ItemCount}" Margin="5,0"/>
                                                </DockPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid>
```

I don't test it, so I hope you got idea. If not, please give me known. I try explain more

Comment: Hi, I am new to .net, i am from java background and have verly little knowledge about .net and wpf. If you dont mind can you explain what you have done and how it works? or point me to some materials where i can get a clear idea of this.

Comment: after playing with you code, I think it's better to use TreeView, so see @Viktor La Croix comment to your question (or this http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/davids/archive/2010/04/17/hierarchical-grid-with-wpf.aspx); if you need exactly DataGrid, you can see this msdn article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd833072(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Just a comment: if you come from a Java background, and have to work in WPF, forget everything you've ever learned. WPF requires a huge mindshift with respect to any other technologies out there. You have to think UI separate from data (and functionality). Take a look at MVVM pattern.